# State of Rectangle changes only when Clicking PyQt5 QML

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have my new PyQt5 Application. I wanted to add inside QMainWindow the QQuickWidget and set his properties with QML. This is what I do:

```
class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,600)

        engine = PyQt5.QtQml.QQmlEngine(self)
        view = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget(engine,self)
        view.setSource(PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl("files/newqml.qml"))
```

into the QML file I create the Rectangle with States which should be changed when mouse is hovering the button. But when it is hovered - nothing is going on. State changes when I click on the button and when I click and leave button. Help me, please. How can I make it right? 
**Full QML Code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle{
  signal buttonPressedSignal
  signal buttonReleasedSignal
  id: topButton
  width:80
  height: 40
  color: 'white'
  border {width: 2; color: '#4CAF50'}
  state: 'Normal'
  Text {
    id: buttonText
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text:'Button'
    font.pixelSize: 20
    font.family: 'Hallo sans'
    color: 'black'
  }
  MouseArea{
    anchors.fill: topButton
    hoverEnabled: true
    onPressed: parent.buttonPressedSignal()
    onReleased: parent.buttonReleasedSignal()
    onEntered: parent.state='NotNormal'
    onExited: parent.state = 'Normal'
  }
  states:[
    State{
      name: 'Normal';
      PropertyChanges{target:buttonText;color:'black';easing.type:Easing.InOutElastic}
    },
    State{
      name:'NotNormal';
      PropertyChanges{target:buttonText;color:'white';easing.type:Easing.InOutElastic}
    }
  ]
  transitions:[
  Transition{
    to: '*'
    ColorAnimation{target:buttonText;duration:400}
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You could place the QML code

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not added the `QQuickWidget` to the `QMainWindow` correctly, you must use `setCentralWidget` or the layouts to place them. Also the qml has an error easing.type is part of `PropertyAnimation` and not of `PropertyChanges`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtQml, QtQuickWidgets, QtCore


class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWindow,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,600)

        engine = QtQml.QQmlEngine(self)
        view = QtQuickWidgets.QQuickWidget(engine,self)
        view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl("files/newqml.qml"))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = mainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle{
    signal buttonPressedSignal
    signal buttonReleasedSignal
    id: topButton
    width:80
    height: 40
    color: 'white'
    border {width: 2; color: '#4CAF50'}
    state: 'Normal'
    Text {
        id: buttonText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text:'Button'
        font.pixelSize: 20
        font.family: 'Hallo sans'
        color: 'black'
    }
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: topButton
        hoverEnabled: true
        onPressed: parent.buttonPressedSignal()
        onReleased: parent.buttonReleasedSignal()
        onEntered: parent.state='NotNormal'
        onExited: parent.state = 'Normal'
    }
    states:[
        State{
            name: 'Normal';
            PropertyChanges{target:buttonText;color:'black';}
        },
        State{
            name:'NotNormal';
            PropertyChanges{target:buttonText;color:'white';}
        }
    ]
    transitions:[
        Transition{
            to: '*'
            ColorAnimation{target:buttonText;duration:400}
            PropertyAnimation{target:buttonText; easing.type:Easing.InOutElastic;}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @eyllanesc, setCentralWidget works fine :)